# Using RUN in Dockerfile to install Laravel inside a php image is not working

Tags: php, laravel, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to install Laravel inside a php container using this line on my Dockerfile:

```
RUN composer create-project laravel/laravel=8.* . --prefer-dist
```

My goal is to install it on my container directory `/var/www/html`. My first assumption is that by using `.` , the command ran on the current working directory, which is `/var/www/html` itself. And actually, it works when I go inside the container and run the command there. But, when building using the Dockerfile, seems that it doesn't install anything anywhere. On the contrary, the message I got on the terminal looked like the command ran successfully:

```
=> [stage-0 6/6] RUN composer create-project laravel/laravel=8.* . --prefer-dist
```

Currently my `docker-compose.yaml` looked like this:

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  # PHP + Apache Service
  php-apache:
    build:
      context: ./php-apache
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./src/:/var/www/html
      - ./php-apache/apache2.conf:/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
      - ./php-apache/000-default.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
    depends_on:
      mysql:
        condition: service_healthy

# other services and volumes...
```

Also my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.1-apache

# Mysql driver on php
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mysqli

# Composer
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git zip
COPY --from=composer:2.2.2 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Node.js 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs npm

# Laravel
RUN composer create-project laravel/laravel=8.* . --prefer-dist
```

I already set the `working_dir` to `/var/www/html`. Why is that the case here?

Comment: Also share your Dockerfile. You might consider running that in an entry script

Comment: @EmekaMbah Hi Emeka, I already shared the complete Dockerfile. Kindly review the question. Also, what's an _entry script_? A quick google search for it doesn't show anything specific to Laravel or Docker.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what's the reason to use `create-project` in a Dockerfile? Wouldn't this create a new project each time you start this container?

Comment: The entry point script runs after the container has started. Can you add it to the end of your Dockerfile? 

`CMD composer create-project laravel/laravel=8.* . --prefer-dist "daemon off;"`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the entry point script to run scripts after the container has started.

Create a bash script in the same location where you have Dockerfile.

**start-container.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#This will try to install laravel in /var/www/html/new-laravel if folder does not exists

composer create-project laravel/laravel=8.* /var/www/html/new-laravel --prefer-dist

#If your container gets exited, then consider restarting apache, here is an #example
#service php7.4-fpm start && nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

Remember to make the bash script executable, run the command before you run docker-compose build

```
chmod u+x start-container.sh
```

Then in your Dockerfile towards the end add:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["start-container"]
```

Then:

```
docker-compose stop && docker-compose build && docker-compose up -d
```